# Broken drawing shapes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

In trying to Implement paint, I decided to begin with shapes
My init:

```
 def __init__(self, parent=None): 
    self.modified = False
    self.rectangle = False
    self.ellipse = False
    self.begin = QPoint()
    self.end = QPoint()
    self.myPenWidth = 1
    self.myFigureColor = Qt.black
    self.image = QImage()
```

I have an event in which there are functions for drawing shapes

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if (event.button() == Qt.LeftButton) and self.rectangle:
        self.draw_rectandle(event)
    if (event.button() == Qt.LeftButton) and self.ellipse:
        self.draw_ellipse(event)
```

Here we use the function in which is located a drawing figures:
I'll post them below

```
def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    if (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton) and self.rectangle:
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()
    if (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton) and self.ellipse:
        self.end = event.pos()
        self.update()
```

And

```
def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
    if (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton) and self.rectangle:
        self.begin = event.pos()
        self.end = event.pos()
    if (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton) and self.ellipse:
        self.begin = event.pos()
        self.end = event.pos()
```

And another function paintEvent:

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    painter = QPainter(self)
    dirtyRect = event.rect()
    painter.drawImage(dirtyRect, self.image, dirtyRect)
    if self.rectangle == True:
        painter.setPen(QPen(self.myFigureColor, self.myPenWidth,
                            Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
        painter.drawRect(QRect(self.begin, self.end))
    if self.ellipse == True:
        painter.setPen(QPen(self.myFigureColor, self.myPenWidth,
                            Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
        painter.drawEllipse(QRect(self.begin, self.end))
```

The functions of figures themselves:

```
def draw_rectandle(self, event):
    painter = QPainter(self.image)
    painter.setPen(QPen(self.myFigureColor, self.myPenWidth,
                        Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
    painter.drawRect(QRect(self.begin, self.end))
    self.begin = event.pos()
    self.end = event.pos()
    self.modified = True
    self.update()

def draw_ellipse(self, event):
    painter = QPainter(self.image)
    painter.setPen(QPen(self.myFigureColor, self.myPenWidth,
                        Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
    painter.drawEllipse(QRect(self.begin, self.end))
    self.begin = event.pos()
    self.end = event.pos()
    self.modified = True
    self.update()
```

Also "pseudo binds"

```
def rectangleOn(self):
    self.ellipse = False
    self.rectangle = True

def ellipseOn(self):
    self.rectangle = False
    self.ellipse = True
```

They are used to change the function flags when the shape button is pressed.
The buttons themselves look like if you need to:

Actions:

```
    self.rectangle = QAction(QIcon('Image/rectangle.png'), 'Rectangle', self)
    self.rectangle.triggered.connect(self.scribbleArea.rectangleOn)

    self.ellipse = QAction(QIcon('Image/Ellipse.png'), 'Ellipse', self)
    self.ellipse.triggered.connect(self.scribbleArea.ellipseOn)
```

Toolbar with button:

```
    toolbar = self.addToolBar('Tools')
    toolbar.addAction(self.rectangle)
    toolbar.addAction(self.ellipse)
```

I think that there is no need for a function to change the color and size. Therefore, while I will not post.

Now I'll tell you what the problem is.

In paintEvent, I have a drawing showing a shape. That is, we pull the edge, and see how the shape changes. But then from there it is not saved anywhere.

And in mousePressEvent already drawing the rectangle itself without this drag animation

It seems that all is well, but here there is a bug

As you can see, the drawing of the rectangle goes to the mousePressEvent. And this means that the rectangle appears only when I start drawing the next one. This is already a mistake. BUT! If I draw a few rectangles and start drawing an ellipse, the last rectangle becomes an ellipse.

And also with other my shapes.

If I start drawing a line, and then switch to an ellipse and start drawing ellipse in another place, the line drawn by me will immediately become a very narrow ellipse.

Therefore, I need to somehow pull out this function from the mousePressEvent, so that the desired shape is drawn, with such switching between tools.

If you need more details, write с:

P.S. I apologize for my English, if something is wrong с:

Comment: please, provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not reproduce because you show your code to pieces, I recommend you always show a united code so we can easily execute those that we want to help.

As you have noticed, you must save the data in the image if you want them to remain and the temporary data to paint them directly in the widget. The logic of my solution is that from `mousePressEvent` until an instant before `mouseReleaseEvent` is painted directly in the widget, and then saved in the image, for this I created a class called `AbstractScribbleArea` that implements that general logic, and if you want to implement the logic for other shapes you should only overwrite the `draw()` method.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class AbstractScribbleArea(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AbstractScribbleArea, self).__init__(parent)
        self._start = QtCore.QPoint()
        self._end = QtCore.QPoint()
        self._pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap() 
        self._shape = ""

        self._color = QtGui.QColor("black")
        self._pen_width = 1

        self._pen = QtGui.QPen(self._color, self._pen_width, 
            QtCore.Qt.SolidLine, QtCore.Qt.RoundCap, QtCore.Qt.RoundJoin)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self._start = event.pos()
            self._end = event.pos()
            self.update()
        super(AbstractScribbleArea, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & QtCore.Qt.LeftButton:
            self._end = event.pos()
            self.update()
        super(AbstractScribbleArea, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        # draw on image
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self._pixmap)
        painter.setPen(self._pen)
        self.draw(painter, self._start, self._end, True)

        self._start = QtCore.QPoint()
        self._end = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.update()
        super(AbstractScribbleArea, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self._pixmap, self.rect())
        painter.setPen(self._pen)
        self.draw(painter, self._start, self._end, False)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        w = self.width() if self.width() > self._pixmap.width() else self._pixmap.width()
        h = self.height() if self.height() > self._pixmap.height() else self._pixmap.height()

        s = QtCore.QSize(w, h)
        if s != self._pixmap.size():
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(self._pixmap)
            self._pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(s)
            painter = QtGui.QPainter(self._pixmap)
            painter.fillRect(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, w, h), QtCore.Qt.white)
            painter.drawPixmap(pixmap.rect(), pixmap)
        super(AbstractScribbleArea, self).resizeEvent(event)

    def draw(self, painter, start, end, is_released):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(640, 480)

    def set_pen_width(self, width):
        self._pen.setWidth(width)

    def set_pen_color(self, color):
        self._pen.setColor(QtGui.QColor(color))

    def set_shape(self, shape):
        self._shape =shape

    def shape(self):
        return self._shape


class ScribbleArea(AbstractScribbleArea):
    def draw(self, painter, start, end, is_released):
        if start.isNull() or end.isNull():
            return
        if self.shape() == "rectangle":
            self.draw_rectangle(painter, start, end)
        elif self.shape() == "ellipse":
            self.draw_ellipse(painter, start, end)

    def draw_rectangle(self, painter, start, end):
        rect = QtCore.QRect(start, end)
        painter.drawRect(rect)

    def draw_ellipse(self, painter, start, end):
        rect = QtCore.QRect(start, end)
        painter.drawEllipse(rect)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def rectangleOn(self):
        self.set_shape("rectangle")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def ellipseOn(self):
        self.set_shape("ellipse")


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.scribbleArea = ScribbleArea()
        self.scribbleArea.set_pen_width(10)
        self.scribbleArea.set_pen_color("red")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.scribbleArea)
        self.rectangle = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('Image/rectangle.png'), 'Rectangle', self)
        self.rectangle.triggered.connect(self.scribbleArea.rectangleOn)
        self.ellipse = QtWidgets.QAction(QtGui.QIcon('Image/Ellipse.png'), 'Ellipse', self)
        self.ellipse.triggered.connect(self.scribbleArea.ellipseOn)
        toolbar = self.addToolBar('Tools')
        toolbar.addAction(self.rectangle)
        toolbar.addAction(self.ellipse)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```